# Facebook Multiple Tabs

Tags: facebook, tabs

I would like to add Tabs on my Facebook Page - Welcome, Register, Deals etc. Do i need to create that many facebook applications and then serve it or can i can one application and have many tabs and serve them from the same ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have many "Page Tab apps" that you would add to your page, as different tabs. But if you are fine with having only one tab in your page, and then have more tabs within that, then you can make just one "page tab app" and add it to your page.
So i guess its mainly a ux issue. So if you want users to first navigate to your new tab and then have them see more tabs in its iframe, then you add one page tab app. Otherwise if you want many tabs in your page itself then you will need to make more page tab apps for each functionality.
I don't think it's possible to have one app serve many tabs into your Facebook page, as you can specify only one url from where to pull data, plus you can't specify more than one tab name, which basically means that a Facebook page tab app can have only one page tab within Facebook. However that url could have tabs (like any web app) but obviously those will be rendered within the iframe for that tab in your page.
i hope this answers your question. seems a little confusing to myself! Do ask for clarifications if required.